# Is it right to flag an answer to be un-deleted that I thought was unfairly deleted?

Tags: support, flags

When I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839496/strange-behavior-error-happens-but-exception-isnt-thrown) the user Switft had [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16839591/80274) (10k only link) and received one up vote, he gave the correct answer but I thought it could be explained better, so I added my answer.

Later [Flexo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) deleted the answer Swift had provided, I felt that Swift had answered correctly and deserved the rep he got from the +1 someone gave him.

I flagged the deleted answer so a moderator could look at it and undelete the answer, but I got this in my Flags page

> This answer was here before mine, and his bare
>   bones answer inspired me to write my more detailed one covering the
>   same thing he did. I don't think he deserves to have his answer
>   deleted. Yea its a little lacking in detail, but he did answer the
>   question. – 5 hours ago   **declined - flags should only be used to make
>   moderators aware of content that requires their intervention**

I would think that reversing a deletion a moderator performed would be something that deserves their intervention.

Was I wrong to use the flag button to bring this issue up, or should I have used a different method to contact a moderator? I tried to find a chat room that was appropriate but I could not figure out which one I should have used. What should I do in the future when things like this happen?

Answer (score 7):

> Was I wrong to use the flag button to bring this issue up, or should I have used a different method to contact a moderator?

Nope, you were right. However, flagging for a moderator doesn't mean that the moderator will agree with you or take the action you'd like them to take.

In this case, I also disagree with the deletion, so I restored the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I am the one who declined your flag today.

First, for the record, you are absolutely correct to flag such an answer for mod attention if you believe it was wrongly deleted. For mod-deleted posts, that is the only way to get it undeleted.

After reading over *your* answer more closely than I did when handling the flag, I am not sure I was correct to decline it. In my opinion, the answer is of relatively low-quality; even your initial answer gave much more useful information, but I do not think it qualified to be deleted.

Anna has already undeleted it, so that solves that!

---

Additionally, even if I was correct to decline your flag, it seems I used the wrong reason; As I noted above, moderator attention *was* required to reinstate that post. *If I had been correct*, I probably should have used the "No evidence" reason.

Comment: Yeah, definitely not a killer answer there, but not delete-worthy by any means. :)

Comment: That should have been a comment, not an anwer.

Comment: @Rosinante Not necessarily. It wasn't really fleshed out, but it's an answer. Someone else expanded it into a *better* answer, and that's okay.

Comment: Offering a debugging strategy, in my opinion, is never an answer. The use of terms like 'perhaps' or 'try this' are red flags. But that's my opinion.

Comment: @rosinante I actually agree with that principle 100%, and that may be most of why I declined the flag to undelete. But the question in this case seems only to have been asking how to debug. That's not how I first read the question, but once I went back to it...